# Slow Visual Studio Performance when debugging multithreaded WPF application

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, profiling

I am debugging a C# WPF application (VS2019) that runs n threads simultaneously with the same processing.

Issue: When running in debug build for development, the performance is very slow, and borderline unusable. However, when I switch on the profiling or compile in release mode, there is no longer any performance issues and it runs great.

Question: How can I achieve such performance also in debug mode, so that our other developers can debug with the application in a much higher performance scenario, yet still place breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Request you to analyse the ram in the performance tab of Task Manager while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

To activate Diagnostic Tools go to **'Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools'**

[image]